# Azure Continuous Integration with user uploads

Tags: azure, deployment, continuous-integration

I have configured my online TFS account with Azure websites that means when I commit my changes it automatically deploys latest commit to production.

The problem I am having now is that every deployment flushes everything old and replace it with new files including resources/images i.e. remove user uploaded images/files.

Is there any way I can exclude some folders where I can put user uploaded images and files so CI don't override it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be preferable to store user data outside the website's file system, leaving it only for application code.

You can use Blob Storage for storing files, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12296277/376366).

Comment: Seems like this is the only way.